# Browser support for CSS :first-child and :last-child

Tags: css, browser, css-selectors

Does anyone know which browsers/version support them?

Is it safe to use them, or should I resort to PHP / javascript to generate first/last classes?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=:first-child http://caniuse.com/#search=:last-child

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[`:first-child` and `:last-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html), along with complimentary [compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/).

`:first-child` is supported IE9 properly, and IE7 and IE8 sort of (see chart).

`:last-child` is supported by IE9+ only.

Both of them are supported well by the good browsers.

Comment: i wonder if you do support `first-child` why you shouldn't do `last-child` ? weird!

Comment: I often think the same thing as well. It's probably due to the internal implementation of something in the CSS or rendering engine. At any rate, IE9+ has decent enough market share to make it the minimum supported version of IE

Answer (score 10):

["Can I use..."](http://caniuse.com/) should be your go to resource for these types of questions. Here's are the compatibility tables:

`first-child` - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

`last-child` - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: Except that these links don't explain IE8's partial support (yet).  I'm just about to add the details and send a pull-request.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [nice table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) illustrating different browser support.