# How do i add a style to a specific list element, i.e. single <li> inside <nav> in this?

Tags: css

I have a problem regarding **CSS** styling for my list.

Here is the code.

**CSS**

```
NAV {
width: 940px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
font-family: Geneva,Arial;
border: 1px solid #000000;
background-color: #D0DBF0;}

NAV ul {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 70px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
NAV li {
    display: inline;

}

NAV li a {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 2px solid #00DBF0;
    width: 100px;  
    font-size: 14px; 
    padding: 0px 10px;
    color: #0000FF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<NAV>
        <UL>
            <LI><a href="#">Home</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#">About Us</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#">Contact Us</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#">Red Widgets</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#">Blue Widgets</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#">Green Widgets</a></LI>
        </UL>
    </NAV>
```

So here i have designed everything for navigation list, but for the first list i.e home.

`<LI><a href="#">Home</a></LI>` i want right border. please help me.

Comment: You are writing in capital letter for your tags declaration .. what's the doctype ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using the [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) pseudo-class:

```
nav li:first-child
```

or

```
nav li:first-child a
```

depending on whether you want to target the list item (`<li>`) or anchor (`<a>`).

Comment: ok cool, but what if i need that for the second item in the list?

Comment: Use the `:nth-of-type` selector, e.g. `:nth-of-type(2)`

Comment: well i used 
`NAV li a:first-child {
border-left: 3px solid red;}`
 but the border got applied to all the `<li>` :-(

Comment: note that i have already given right border to all the `<li>` in styling `<nav li a>` in css. is it causing any problem?

Comment: yup! that makes it :) thank you @AnthonyGrist.
now its my time to learn pseudo-class! :D

Comment: li:nth-of-type(even){
    background-color: red;
}
li:nth-of-type(odd){
    background-color: yellow;
}

Answer (score 2):

You should add a class, or id.

For example (Let's also assume later you want a "current selected" item):

**CSS:**

```
.first a { /* specific style for first item */ }
.current a { /* specific style for current item */}
```

**HTML:**

```
<NAV>
        <UL>
            <LI class="first"><a href="#">Home</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#">About Us</a></LI>
            <LI class="current"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></LI>
            ...

            <!-- if the first item happens to be the curent one: -->
            <LI class="first current"><a href="#">Home</a></LI>
        </UL>
</NAV>
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5faP9/)

Comment: css selector solution seems to be more elegant.

Comment: @DanielCheng True for the simple case asked by OP. However the class approache has some advantages: It has better [browser support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938521/browser-support-for-css-first-child-and-last-child), tought it's not a big deal anymore. And I find it better in the case you want a "current" highlighted element, which you almost always want. But let's not argue. Let both solutions be here, and everyone chose whatever is fitting.

Comment: @pinouchon - It doesn't work as i have already given border to the whole `<nav>` .
Now again i need to give border  to the first element inside that `<nav>`

Comment: @PavanNadig You're right. You have to specify styles on the `a` inside the `li` to override the previous rule. I edited my answer and added a jsFiddle to make it work.