# Re-using floatLeft and floatRight to right align text

Tags: html, css, css-float, right-align

How can i right-align text as below. I want product, price and year to be right-aligned.

```
   product       Computer
     price       $1500
      year       2013
```

Currently the html code below gives layout as shown

```
product     Computer
price       $1500
year        2013   

<div style="clear: both;display: block;">
     <p style="float: left">
         <strong>product</strong>
     </p>
     <p style="float: left">
         <span>Computer</span>
     </p>    
</div>

<div style="clear: both;display: block;">
     <p style="float: left">
         <strong>price</strong>
     </p>
     <p style="float: left">
         <span>$1500</span>
     </p>    
</div>

<div style="clear: both;display: block;">
     <p style="float: left">
         <strong>year</strong>
     </p>
     <p style="float: left">
         <span>2013</span>
     </p>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try display: inline-block, does wonders

Answer (score 0):

Try aligning the left-floated words with `text-align:right;`.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it using inline-block elements instead of floating ones. To stick a little to your markup you could do:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
     <span>product</span>
     <span>computer</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
     <span>price</span>
     <span>$1500</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.row > span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

div.row > span:last-child {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/7QeBt/)

As a note: You might think of using another element for your content:

> A paragraph is typically a run of phrasing content that forms a block of text with one or more sentences that discuss a particular topic, as in typography, but can also be used for more general thematic grouping. For instance, an address is also a paragraph, as is a part of a form, a byline, or a stanza in a poem.

If your data  is actually tabular, you can use a `<table>`-element instead. You can also go with some markup like I did, or you can even use a definition list `<dl>` or an unsorted list `<ul>`.

**Edit**

As requested in the comments. Here's a version using a table:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Computer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>1500 USD</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 350px;
}

table > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/QxxsY/)

Comment: last-child is not compatible with all browsers

Comment: @overule Then simply use `first-child` instead, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M5v9Z/).

Comment: same result. Those css are browser specific

Comment: @overule What browser do you need to support? Even IE7 supports `first-child`. You can still use a class instead.

Comment: i believe it is not compatible with IE8

Comment: @overule Take a look at this question: [Browser support for CSS :first-child and :last-child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938521/browser-support-for-css-first-child-and-last-child)

Comment: Can you update the example using tables instead? Would be much better

Comment: @overule I've updated the answer with an example using a table.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<p>` tags some width and margin to your last child element inside the `<div>`. Then assign `text-align: right` to your first child element. It should look something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hEcAX/)**.

Comment: first-child & last-child is not compatible with all browsers especially IE8

Comment: `first-child` is compatitable with IE8. `last-child` is not, but still there is a simple way to change the CSS without using it.