# how to hide first and last element from the three same element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have three div with the same class name, I want to hide the first and last div.

My code:

```
<div class="clsname">div1</div>
<div class="clsname">div2</div>
<div class="clsname">div3</div>
```

Now i want to hide *div1* and *div3*. In fact i want this **output** in browser:

```
div2
```

How can i do that ?

For clarification, I want something like this: (this would hide only *div3* )

```
div.clsname + div.clsname + div.clsname {display:none;}
```

Comment: You could add a new class to div1 and div3 and apply the `{display:none;}` rule to it.

Comment: It depends on the rest of your markup. There's **NO** `:first-of-class`/`:last-of-class` things in CSS.

Comment: @HashemQolami You are assuming that, but he never ask for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this simple CSS:

```
div.clsname:first-child, div.clsname:last-child{
    display:none;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/aLaw2qj5/

Comment: All modern browsers, including IE9+. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938521/browser-support-for-css-first-child-and-last-child.

Comment: `:last-child` is not supported in IE < 9. Also it doesn't respect the classes, it looks for the child element itself matching the rest of the selectors.

Comment: @HashemQolami This works If the three divs are the only children in the parent. And in that case, the OP's solution in the question (using plus signs) will work to get around the missing `:last-child` problem.

Comment: it's also pretty bad to over-qualify a selector with an html tag, not best practice

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by following

```
var elements = jQuery(".clsname");
for (var i = 0 ; < elements.length; i++) {
     if( i == 0 || i = elements.length -1) {
           jQuery(element[i]).style("display" : "none");
     }

}
```

This will hide the 1st and last element with specific class.

Comment: Is it impossible to do that via CSS ?

Comment: Yes. just as lmgonzalves said

Comment: Thanks Bro, just i want to know `div.clsname:first-child` will support in what ver of browsers ?

Comment: It should work in all browser. Please refer to "http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp"

Comment: Why not to use vanilla JavaScript rather than jQuery? You could simply iterate over `document.getElementsByClassName("clsname")` to match the proper elements,

Comment: @HashemQolami I don't want to use `js`

Answer (score 2):

lmgonzalves can be a valid answer. But you don't show all your markup, so Hashem Qolami is right, it could not be what you want.

May be a better solution could be

```
.clsname, .clsname + .clsname + .clsname { display: none;}
.clsname + .clsname { display: block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div.clsname:first-child{
  display:none;
}

div.clsname:last-child{
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: @lmgonzalves And none of the two answers work if `div.clsname` is not matching exactly the first or last ***child*** of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that targets only the three divs with the class and leaves the other divs alone. (So it works either with or without other divs in between.)

```css
div.clsname, div.clsname ~ div.clsname ~ div.clsname {display:none}
div.clsname ~ div.clsname {display:block}
```

```html
<div>Other div, displayed normally</div>
<div class="clsname">div1</div>
<div>Other div, displayed normally</div>
<div>Other div, displayed normally</div>
<div class="clsname">div2</div>
<div>Other div, displayed normally</div>
<div>Other div, displayed normally</div>
<div>Other div, displayed normally</div>
<div class="clsname">div3</div>
<div>Other div, displayed normally</div>
<div>Other div, displayed normally</div>
<div>Other div, displayed normally</div>
<div>Other div, displayed normally</div>
```

Compatible with all modern browsers, and even IE8.