# How do i add vertical line on my menu item in html/css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a menu navigation like this:

> start fire | our fires | past fires

I want the menu items to be separated by vertical lines as opposed to spaces

```
<ul class="standard-nav visible-lg">
    <li><a id="intro-linker" class="scroll" href="#intro">Start a fire</a></li>
    <li><a id="about-linker" class="scroll" href="#ourfires">Our fire</a></li>
    <li><a id="services-linker" class="scroll" href="#pastfires">Past fires</a></li>
    <li><a id="team-linker" class="scroll" href="#team">Chief fire lighter</a></li>
    <li><a id="portfolio-linker" class="scroll" href="#seriesfires">Series of fires</a></li>
    <li><a id="contact-linker" class="scroll" href="#contact">Get fired up</a></li>
</ul>
```

The css is here:

```
.standard-nav{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: right;
}
.standard-nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}    
.standard-nav li > a{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Vegur Light";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    line-height:19px;
    /*text-transform: uppercase;*/
}
```

Comment: jQuery UI tabs could work, but are overkill; [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11574821/410342) is a decent CSS-only example. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/A52T8/234/

Answer (score 7):

You can use pseudo-element `:after` alongside `:not(:last-child)` to not apply this to last element:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "|";
  }
```

```html
<ul class="standard-nav visible-lg">
  <li><a id="intro-linker" class="scroll" href="#intro">Start a fire</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="about-linker" class="scroll" href="#ourfires">Our fire</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="services-linker" class="scroll" href="#pastfires">Past fires</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="team-linker" class="scroll" href="#team">Chief fire lighter</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="portfolio-linker" class="scroll" href="#seriesfires">Series of fires</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="contact-linker" class="scroll" href="#contact">Get fired up</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

For IE8 support reverse the logic of css rule:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "|";
}
```

```html
<ul class="standard-nav visible-lg">
  <li><a id="intro-linker" class="scroll" href="#intro">Start a fire</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="about-linker" class="scroll" href="#ourfires">Our fire</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="services-linker" class="scroll" href="#pastfires">Past fires</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="team-linker" class="scroll" href="#team">Chief fire lighter</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="portfolio-linker" class="scroll" href="#seriesfires">Series of fires</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="contact-linker" class="scroll" href="#contact">Get fired up</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**References**

[:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter)

[:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)

[:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-child)

Comment: so i do away with the css completely

Comment: @BillehSarkozy If I understand right, yes you can do it with pure css.

Comment: Since [IE8 supports `:first-child` but not `:last-child`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938521/browser-support-for-css-first-child-and-last-child), I prefer to place the pipe character `:before` every list item and then override it for `:first-child`.

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks for the feedback. Updated. To be honest I never have IE8 in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS `border`:

```
.standard-nav li {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.standard-nav li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/L6wjrugb/)

**Shorter**

```
.standard-nav li:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/L6wjrugb/1/)

Comment: I would apply the border to the `<ul>` element instead of `<li>`.

Comment: how do i add space in between the text and the diagonal line

Comment: @BillehSarkozy Use `padding` on `li` http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/L6wjrugb/3/

Comment: i want spacing on both the left and right.when i put padding right it is not reflecting

Comment: is there a way to increase the height of the red line

Comment: @BillehSarkozy Use `line-height` on `li` to set the `height` of separator

Answer (score 0):

You may see this [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/npralhad/uvb2Lpqc/5/).

**Whole HTML code:**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<style>
.standard-nav{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: right;
}
.standard-nav li{
    border-right: 2px solid #c4c4c4;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.standard-nav li:last-child {
    border-right:0;
} 
.standard-nav li > a{
    color: red;
    font-family: "Vegur Light";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    line-height:19px;
    /*text-transform: uppercase;*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="standard-nav visible-lg">
    <li><a id="intro-linker" class="scroll" href="#intro">Start a fire</a></li>
    <li><a id="about-linker" class="scroll" href="#ourfires">Our fire</a></li>
    <li><a id="services-linker" class="scroll" href="#pastfires">Past fires</a></li>
    <li><a id="team-linker" class="scroll" href="#team">Chief fire lighter</a></li>
    <li><a id="portfolio-linker" class="scroll" href="#seriesfires">Series of fires</a></li>
    <li><a id="contact-linker" class="scroll" href="#contact">Get fired up</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**You will observe:**

1. Right Border is applied to each `li`
2. Right Border is removed for last `li`
3. I have changed the LINK `color` to red just for a demo purpose - you may latter remove that.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
li+li { border-left: 1px solid #000000 }
```

this will affect only adjecent li elements

found here http://www.jackreichert.com/2011/07/31/how-to-add-a-divider-between-menu-items-in-css-using-only-one-selector/