# CSS - Hide middle <li> element in <ul>

Tags: css

I have the following html :

```
<div class="dashboard-widget big-counter">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <div class="title">Pageview</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="title">Order</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="title">Sales</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="title">Earning</div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- .big-counter -->
```

I am trying to hide the last 3 `<li>` elements out of the 4, so I only need to have the "Pageview" first `<li>` element visible.

I've read in another question that the most browser compatible way of doing this would be `li + li` trick, so to hide the first element, the CSS would be as follows :

```
.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li {
display: none !Important;
}

.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li + li {
display: list-item !Important;
}
```

But that works great for the first element.

How can I skip the first element and hide the last 3 with this method ?

Or any other browser compatible method ?

My fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/03w0kk4t/

Answer (score 3):

You could use CSS's `nth-child()`:

```
.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li:nth-child(2),  /*this element's 2nd child*/
.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li:nth-child(3),  /*this element's 3rd child*/
.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li:nth-child(4) { /*this element's 4th child*/
    display: none !important;
}
```

Then, use either `nth-child(1)` or `:first-child` to select the first element

```
.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li:nth-child(1) {
    display: list-item !important;
}
```

**or**

```
.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li:first-child {
    display: list-item !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/zqm2osso/

Comment: What about hiding all the li elements then only showing the first; `.list-inline li {display:none;}
.list-inline li:nth-child(1){ display:block; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li:first-child {
display: list-item !Important;
}
```

Or you can target `first child`.
http://jsfiddle.net/03w0kk4t/4/

About browser support: [Browser support for CSS :first-child and :last-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938521/browser-support-for-css-first-child-and-last-child)

P.S. `!important` is not needed, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CSS, Try this.

```
.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  display: none !Important;
}
.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li + li {
display: list-item !Important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 Selectors to make the behavior you want. Use [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) for more help.

Example of css

```
li:nth-child(2),li:nth-child(3),li:nth-child(4){display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most browser compatible solution is indeed by using the adjacent sibling selector `li + li` (IE7+ and modern browsers). You just have to put `display: none` to this rule and let first element display by default.

```css
.dashboard-widget.big-counter ul.list-inline li + li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-widget big-counter">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
      <div class="title">Pageview</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="title">Order</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="title">Sales</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="title">Earning</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- .big-counter -->
```

Reference: [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)