# JQuery show delete button on appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have so far able to remove each appened elements using `.remove()` function of JQuery. my problem is the delete button is always showing on the first element.

I want to hide the delete button on first element and show the delete button when I append a new element.

I have set the delete button on the first element to

```
 .delete-button:first-child{
    display:none;
 }
```

in my css but all succeeding appends do not show the delete button..
how can I do this with JQuery can it be done using CSS only?

Comment: Since it is first child I don't think it can done by just using css. If it is last child then it can be done using css.

Comment: could u provide some markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
li:first-child .delete-button { display:none }
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
     First <button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
</li>
<li>
     Second <button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
</li>
</ul>
```

Making assumptions on your markup since none was provided. You can accomplish it using css.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of your requirement: If there is only one item, do not show a delete button; if there are multiple items, show a delete button for *every* item.

Your attempt didn't work because `.delete-button:first-child` selects all elements with the `delete-button` class that are also the `first-child` of their parent element. Presumably this would be all of your buttons.

You can instead use the [`:only-of-type` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type) on the elements that *contain* the delete buttons, e.g., assuming they have the `item` class:

```
.item:only-of-type .delete-button { display: none; }
```

Or if they are li elements:

```
li:only-of-type .delete-button { display: none; }
```

That way if the item/li/whatever is the only item then its delete button will be hidden automatically, but as soon as you add additional items the delete button will be shown automatically for *all* items.

Here's a simple demo with a bit of JS to mock up the add and delete functionality:

```js
$("#parent").on("click", ".delete-button", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
$(".add-button").on("click", function() {
  $("#parent").children().first().clone().appendTo("#parent");
});
```

```css
.item:only-of-type .delete-button { display: none; }

.item { margin: 3px; padding: 2px; width: 100px; border: thin black solid; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-button">Add Item</button>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="item">
    <button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
    <div>An item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is good.. but how can I hide the delete button on the first one?? I need the delete button to show only on the succeeding appends..

Comment: You could use the [`:first-of-type` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) with the above, but why would you want no delete button on the first one? What if that's the one the user wants to delete?

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
div ul:not(:first-child) {
    .delete-button{
    display:none;
 }
}
```

Comment: That is not valid css

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna consider browser compatibility before using CSS - [Browser support for CSS :first-child and :last-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938521/browser-support-for-css-first-child-and-last-child)

Having said that, With jQuery you can write an event handler to change css of all the child elements except the last.

Consider this example from [jQuery: How to listen for DOM changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488653/jquery-how-to-listen-for-dom-changes?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
$("element-root").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", "CustomHandler");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible by **css** only. I hope this snippet helps.

```js
$(document).on('click','#AppendList', function(){
 $("ul").append('<li>List <button class="delete-button">Delete</button></li>');
})
```

```css
li .delete-button { display:none }
li:last-child .delete-button { display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>
    First <button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
 </li>
 <li>
    Second <button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
 </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<button type="button" id="AppendList">Add List</button>
```